# In R, use nonstandard evaluation to select specific variables from data.frames

Tags: r, tidyverse, evaluation

I've got several large-ish data.frames set up like a relational database, and I'd like to make a single function to look for whatever variable I need and grab it from that particular data.frame and add it to the data.frame I'm currently working on. I've got a way to do this that works, but it requires temporarily making a list of all the data.frames, which seems inefficient. I suspect that nonstandard evaluation would solve this problem for me, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Here's what works but seems inefficient:

```
Table1 <- data.frame(ID = LETTERS[1:10], ColA = rnorm(10), ColB = rnorm(10),
                     ColC = rnorm(10))

Table2 <- data.frame(ID = LETTERS[1:10], ColD = rnorm(10), ColE = rnorm(10),
                     ColF = rnorm(10))

Table3 <- data.frame(ID = LETTERS[1:10], ColG = rnorm(10), ColH = rnorm(10),
                     ColI = rnorm(10))

Key <- data.frame(Table = rep(c("Table1", "Table2", "Table3"), each = 4),
                  ColumnName = c("ID", paste0("Col", LETTERS[1:3]),
                                 "ID", paste0("Col", LETTERS[4:6]),
                                 "ID", paste0("Col", LETTERS[7:9])))

# function for grabbing info from other tables
grab <- function(StartDF, ColNames){

      AllDFs <- list(Table1, Table2, Table3)
      names(AllDFs) <- c("Table1", "Table2", "Table3")

      # Determine which data.frames have that column
      WhichDF <- Key %>% filter(ColumnName %in% ColNames) %>% 
            select(Table)

      TempDF <- StartDF

      for(i in 1:length(ColNames)){
            ToAdd <- AllDFs[WhichDF[i, 1]]
            ToAdd <- ToAdd[[1]] %>% 
                  select(c(ColNames[i], ID))

            TempDF <- TempDF %>% left_join(ToAdd)
            rm(ToAdd)
      }

      return(TempDF)


}

grab(Table1, c("ColE", "ColH"))
```

What would be great instead would be something like this:

```
grab <- function(StartDF, ColNames){

      # Some function that returns the column names of all the data.frames
      # without me creating a new object that is a list of them

      # Some function that left_joins the correct data.frame plus the column
      # "ID" to my starting data.frame, again without needing to create that list 
      # of all the data.frames

}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have an argument  with the tables to join (in case if you rename the table names differently in the future?

Comment: I see what you're asking, @akrun, but the point of the function is to figure out which other table has the column name I'm looking for. In my actual work, I have a set of 10 data.frames connected by unique IDs like a relational database, and I sometimes want to grab some column that I know is in another data.frame without having to look up *which* data.frame contains that column.

Comment: Try with `WhichDF %>% pull(Table) %>% as.character %>% mget(envir = .GlobalEnv) %>% append(list(Table1), .) %>% reduce(left_join)`

Comment: Is there a way to add *only* the column names specified by `ColNames` in the function?

Comment: It is doing that because I am using the same step in your code `WhichDF <- Key %>% filter(ColumnName %in% ColNames) %>% 
            select(Table)`

Comment: If you meant the corresponding names, then use the same `for` loop from your post after the `append`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating the `list` manually, we can directly get the values of the objects returned from the 'Table' column of 'Key' dataset with `mget`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
grab <- function(StartDF, ColNames){



     # filter the rows of Key based on the ColNames input
     # pull the Table column as a vector
     # column was factor, so convert to character class
     # return the value of the objects with mget in a list
     Tables <- Key %>% 
               filter(ColumnName %in% ColNames) %>% 
               pull(Table) %>%
               as.character %>%
               mget(envir = .GlobalEnv) 


      TempDF <- StartDF

      # use the same left_joins in a loop after selecting only the
      # ID and corresponding columns from 'ColNames'
      for(i in seq_along(ColNames)){
            ToAdd  <- Tables[[i]] %>%
                         select(ColNames[i], ID)          

            TempDF <- TempDF %>% 
                  left_join(ToAdd)
            rm(ToAdd)
      }

      TempDF


}

grab(Table1, c("ColE", "ColH"))
```

---

Or another option is `reduce`

```
grab <- function(StartDF, ColNames) {
     #only change is that instead of a for loop
     # use reduce with left_join after selecting the corresponding columns
     # with map
     Key %>%
       filter(ColumnName %in% ColNames) %>% 
       pull(Table) %>%
       as.character %>%
       mget(envir = .GlobalEnv)  %>%
       map2(ColNames, ~ .x %>%
                     select(ID, .y)) %>%
       append(list(Table1), .)  %>%
       reduce(left_join)

   }

grab(Table1, c("ColE", "ColH"))
#   ID       ColA       ColB        ColC        ColE        ColH
#1   A -0.9490093  0.5177143 -1.91015491  0.07777086  1.86277670
#2   B -0.7182786 -1.1019146 -0.70802738 -0.73965230  0.18375660
#3   C  0.5064516 -1.6904354  1.11106206  2.04315508 -0.65365228
#4   D  0.9362477  0.5260682 -0.03419651 -0.51628310 -1.17104181
#5   E  0.5636047 -0.9470895  0.43303304 -2.95928629  1.86425049
#6   F  1.0598531  0.4144901  0.10239896  1.57681703 -0.05382603
#7   G  1.1335047 -0.8282173 -0.28327898  2.02917831  0.50768462
#8   H  0.2941341  0.3261185 -0.15528127 -0.46470035 -0.86561320
#9   I -2.1434905  0.6567689  0.02298549  0.90822132  0.64360337
#10  J  0.4291258  1.3410147  0.67544567  0.12466251  0.75989623
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! In particular, I'm looking into `mget` and `pull` b/c I'm not familiar with those functions.

Comment: @LauraS ok, I updated with a single `%>%` chain with `reduce`

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not able to get that code to work. What is `cn1`?

Comment: @LauraS Sorry, I forgot to change the `cn1` to `ColNames` (updated)

Comment: Perfect! That's beautifully succinct! Thank you!

Comment: This answer is flawed -- when using `map2` you are expecting that the order of the character vector is the same order as the corresponding tables in the `Key` dataframe.

Comment: @akrun that is not really the same is it? I agree with you that nested lists and lists of vectors are very much not the same and therefore nonsense to use as an argument. But here the question is clearly "given a list of colnames gimme the corresponding tables using this dictionary and join them with my original table". OP hasn't specified that the colnames has to be given in a certain order. Your answer works with that assumption, and I would therefore argue that it is flawed. That's the reason for my downvote. What's the reason for yours?

Comment: @PeterH.  I got your point.  But you are also doing some assumptions in your solution i.e. assuming that the 'Table' data objects are already created in the global env.

Answer (score 0):

There is a serious bug in the accepted solution. If you're not careful with the ordering in the `ColNames` argument, then the function won't work. Also, I redefined your data to use tibbles instead. They're basically the same as data frames, but their default settings are nicer (e.g. you don't need StringsAsFactors = FALSE)

```r
library(tidyverse)

Table1 <- tibble(
  ID = LETTERS[1:10], ColA = rnorm(10), ColB = rnorm(10), ColC = rnorm(10)
)
Table2 <- tibble(
  ID = LETTERS[1:10], ColD = rnorm(10), ColE = rnorm(10), ColF = rnorm(10)
)
Table3 <- tibble(
  ID = LETTERS[1:10], ColG = rnorm(10), ColH = rnorm(10), ColI = rnorm(10)
)

Key <- tibble(
  Table = rep(c("Table1", "Table2", "Table3"), each = 4),
  ColumnName = c("ID", paste0("Col", LETTERS[1:3]),
                 "ID", paste0("Col", LETTERS[4:6]),
                 "ID", paste0("Col", LETTERS[7:9]))
)

grab_akrun <- function(StartDF, ColNames) {
  #only change is that instead of a for loop
  # use reduce with left_join after selecting the corresponding columns
  # with map
  Key %>%
    filter(ColumnName %in% ColNames) %>% 
    pull(Table) %>%
    as.character %>%
    mget(envir = .GlobalEnv)  %>%
    map2(ColNames, ~ .x %>%
           select(ID, .y)) %>%
    append(list(Table1), .)  %>%
    reduce(left_join)

}

grab_akrun(Table1, c("ColE", "ColH"))
#> Joining, by = "ID"Joining, by = "ID"
#> # A tibble: 10 x 6
#>    ID      ColA   ColB   ColC   ColE   ColH
#>    <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 A     -0.658 -0.613  0.689 -0.850 -0.795
#>  2 B      0.143  0.732 -0.212 -1.74   1.99 
#>  3 C     -0.966 -0.570 -0.354  0.559 -1.11 
#>  4 D     -1.05   0.269 -0.856 -0.370 -1.35 
#>  5 E      0.255 -0.349  0.329  1.39   0.421
#>  6 F      1.51   1.38   0.707 -0.639  0.289
#>  7 G     -1.28   1.44  -1.35   1.94  -1.04 
#>  8 H     -1.56  -0.434  0.231  0.467  0.656
#>  9 I     -0.553 -1.64  -0.761  0.133  0.249
#> 10 J     -0.950  0.418 -0.843  0.593  0.343
```

This works, but if you change the order:

```r
grab_akrun(Table1, c("ColH", "ColE"))
#> Error: Unknown column `ColH`
```

Instead, you should approach it like this:

```r
grab_new <- function(StartDF, ColNames) {
  Key %>% 
    filter(ColumnName %in% ColNames) %>% 
    pluck("Table") %>%
    mget(inherits = TRUE) %>% 
    map(~select(.x, ID, intersect(colnames(.x), ColNames))) %>% 
    reduce(left_join, .init = StartDF)
}

grab_new(Table1, c("ColE", "ColH"))
#> Joining, by = "ID"Joining, by = "ID"
#> # A tibble: 10 x 6
#>    ID      ColA   ColB   ColC   ColE   ColH
#>    <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 A     -0.658 -0.613  0.689 -0.850 -0.795
#>  2 B      0.143  0.732 -0.212 -1.74   1.99 
#>  3 C     -0.966 -0.570 -0.354  0.559 -1.11 
#>  4 D     -1.05   0.269 -0.856 -0.370 -1.35 
#>  5 E      0.255 -0.349  0.329  1.39   0.421
#>  6 F      1.51   1.38   0.707 -0.639  0.289
#>  7 G     -1.28   1.44  -1.35   1.94  -1.04 
#>  8 H     -1.56  -0.434  0.231  0.467  0.656
#>  9 I     -0.553 -1.64  -0.761  0.133  0.249
#> 10 J     -0.950  0.418 -0.843  0.593  0.343
grab_new(Table1, c("ColH", "ColE"))
#> Joining, by = "ID"Joining, by = "ID"
#> # A tibble: 10 x 6
#>    ID      ColA   ColB   ColC   ColE   ColH
#>    <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 A     -0.658 -0.613  0.689 -0.850 -0.795
#>  2 B      0.143  0.732 -0.212 -1.74   1.99 
#>  3 C     -0.966 -0.570 -0.354  0.559 -1.11 
#>  4 D     -1.05   0.269 -0.856 -0.370 -1.35 
#>  5 E      0.255 -0.349  0.329  1.39   0.421
#>  6 F      1.51   1.38   0.707 -0.639  0.289
#>  7 G     -1.28   1.44  -1.35   1.94  -1.04 
#>  8 H     -1.56  -0.434  0.231  0.467  0.656
#>  9 I     -0.553 -1.64  -0.761  0.133  0.249
#> 10 J     -0.950  0.418 -0.843  0.593  0.343
```

Which works as expected.

<sup>Created on 2020-01-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>