# Lagging in R when a condition is matched

Tags: r, function, lag

I have a dataframe with just dates of medical checkups and presence of infection (yes/no), and I want to add a third column representing the date of the last infection. The new `last_infection` column should have `NA` if the patient has had no previous infection. If they have had previous infection, it should show the date of the most *recent* visit where they tested "yes" for infection.

I want the output to look like this:

```
date      infection   last_infection
01-01-18  no          NA
06-01-18  no          NA
07-01-18  yes         NA
09-01-18  no          07-01-18
01-01-19  no          07-01-18
02-01-19  yes         07-01-18
03-01-19  yes         02-01-19
04-01-19  no          03-01-19
05-01-19  no          03-01-19
```

How can I do this in R? Can a function like `lag()` check for a condition, or should I do something else entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create a grouping variable based on logical vector created with 'infection' and use that to `lag` the column.  Here, we load only `dplyr` and not any other packages

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(grp = cumsum(infection == "yes")) %>%
   mutate(new = first(date)) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   mutate(new = replace(lag(new), seq_len(match(1, grp)), NA)) %>%
   select(-grp)
# A tibble: 9 x 4
#  date     infection last_infection new     
#  <chr>    <chr>     <chr>          <chr>   
#1 01-01-18 no        <NA>           <NA>    
#2 06-01-18 no        <NA>           <NA>    
#3 07-01-18 yes       <NA>           <NA>    
#4 09-01-18 no        07-01-18       07-01-18
#5 01-01-19 no        07-01-18       07-01-18
#6 02-01-19 yes       07-01-18       07-01-18
#7 03-01-19 yes       02-01-19       02-01-19
#8 04-01-19 no        03-01-19       03-01-19
#9 05-01-19 no        03-01-19       03-01-19
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(date = c("01-01-18", "06-01-18", "07-01-18", "09-01-18", 
"01-01-19", "02-01-19", "03-01-19", "04-01-19", "05-01-19"), 
    infection = c("no", "no", "yes", "no", "no", "yes", "yes", 
    "no", "no"), last_infection = c(NA, NA, NA, "07-01-18", "07-01-18", 
    "07-01-18", "02-01-19", "03-01-19", "03-01-19")),
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: This is excellent, thank you @akrun! Can you explain how the `first(date)` part works?

Comment: @kss What is happening is that the 'grp' column increase value by 1 everytime there is an 'yes' in 'infection' column.  So, when we do the `group_by`, the first observation in 'date' for 'grp' 1 would be at 3rd row, above that it would  be grp 0 (because it was all  'no' in 'infection').  That is the reason I useed the `first`.  Later, wee are `replace`ing the values to `NA` for the first 2 elementss with the starting 'yes'

Comment: Got it, this is extremely helpful. Appreciate it.

Comment: Not clear about the downvote here.  I showed a method without using more external packages.  I remember another downvote  on another question  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59828866/in-r-use-nonstandard-evaluation-to-select-specific-variables-from-data-frames/59841584#59841584) because the other answer post showed some edge cases.  If the same person is doing the downvote, I would report it  because the downvote here is unnecessary.  Let's say, tomorrow another person comes up  with a one-line code, do we downvote other solutions?

Comment: If the patient never had an infection, this code throws an error because there is no grp=1. Is there a way to fix this @akrun? I would want all NA's for the `new` column.

Comment: @kss I  would do `df1 %>% group_by(grp = cumsum(infection == "yes")) %>% mutate(new = if(any(grp > 0)) first(date) else NA) %>% ungroup` in that ccase

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest something like this instead. No reason to use cumsum or grouping if you use `fill` from the tidyr package.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(
    last_infection = if_else(lag(infection) == "yes", lag(date), NA_character_)
  ) %>% 
  fill(last_infection)
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#>   date     infection last_infection
#>   <chr>    <chr>     <chr>         
#> 1 01-01-18 no        <NA>          
#> 2 06-01-18 no        <NA>          
#> 3 07-01-18 yes       <NA>          
#> 4 09-01-18 no        07-01-18      
#> 5 01-01-19 no        07-01-18      
#> 6 02-01-19 yes       07-01-18      
#> 7 03-01-19 yes       02-01-19      
#> 8 04-01-19 no        03-01-19      
#> 9 05-01-19 no        03-01-19
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>